# Add certificate to certdata.txt and build firefox with them

Tags: firefox, certificate, nss

I have to add some certificates to firefox before building it. Then test it with this certificates. I know that certificates are hardcoded into the certdata.txt, in this location:

`mozilla-source\mozilla-central\security\nss\lib\ckfw\builtins`

I've tried to add certificates into the `certdata.txt` using `addbuilit` from `nss-tools`. But after building it I get errors.

Compiler shows this errors when reading `certdata.txt`:

> 0:49.23 c:/mozilla-source/mozilla-central/obj-x86_64-pc-mingw32/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/builtins_nssckbi/certdata.c(20983,1): warning: missing terminating '"' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
>    0:49.23 "\152\270\202\165\004\122\100\146\207\136\301\151\270\325\275\134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's pretty easy to do.

**Firstly** you need a `nss` and `nspr`, because of `nss` that is built in to mozilla installer does not have `addbuiltin` function that we need.

Download NSS for [windows](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_11_RTM/WINNT5.0_OPT.OBJ/)

Download Nspr for [windows](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/nspr/releases/v4.6/WINNT5.0_OPT.OBJ/)

### Second step

unpack both of these files.

Then copy the contents of the NSPR /lib folder to the NSS /bin folder

Copy your certificate and certutil.txt to the NSS /bin folder.
**Note: Your certificate should be in `.der` format!**

### Third step

Run this code bellow:

```
addbuiltin -n "My certificate name" -t "CT,C,C" < CAcert.der >> certdata.txt
```

> `My certificate name` - The name of the certificate that will be added to the `certutil.txt.`
>
> `CT,C,C` - Is the trusted properties of the certificate.
>
> `CAcert.der` - Certificate itself.
>
> `certdata.txt` - Certificates containing file.

But before copying certutil.txt back to the source code you have to do one more thing.
Open certutil.txt in Notepad++ and turn on hidden characters by `Menu View → Show Symbol → Show All Characters`. Then change `/r/n` to `/n`.

### And you've done!